# How to add image in a button html

Tags: html, css

How would i add an image on a button? Right now i am trying to create a banner like thing for a big button but the image doesn't seem to get inside the button as shown here:
[image]
I want the image to be inside the button and not separate each other like that

Here is the `HTML` code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Saharsh | Projects</title>
  
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/Styles/projects.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='../style.css'>
  <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>

  <link rel='icon' type='image/x-icon' href='/Images/Branding/pfp.png'>
</head>

<body class='container'>
  <div id='home'>
    <nav class='navbar'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='../index.html'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#aboutMe'>About me</a></li>
        <li><a href='#moreSoon'>Contact me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

    <br class='us'><br class='us'><br class='us'>
    <br class='us'><br class='us'><br class='us'>
    <br class='us'>

  <div>
    <h1 class='main'>My Projects</h1>
  </div>
    
  <br class='us'><br class='us'><br class='us'>
  <br class='us'>
  
  <div>
    <a href='#aboutMe'><img src='../Images/Projects/Modular-FPS.png' class='banner'><button class='project_button'>Modular FPS Template</button></img></a>
  </div>

  <br class='us'><br class='us'><br class='us'>
  <br class='us'><br class='us'><br class='us'>

  <div>
    <h1 id='moreSoon' style='text-align: center;'>
      <a href='https://github.com/Saharsh1223' target='_blank'><span class='icon_span'><img class='icon' src='/Images/Socials/github.svg'></span></a>
      <a href='https://discord.gg/bkP2P5uuH2' target='_blank'><span class='icon_span'><img class='icon' src='/Images/Socials/discord.svg'></span></a>
      <a href='https://youtube.com/SaharshDev' target='_blank'><span class='icon_span'><img class='icon' src='/Images/Socials/youtube.svg'></span></a>
      <a href='https://twitter.com/Saharsh1223' target='_blank'><span class='icon_span'><img class='icon' src='/Images/Socials/twitter.svg'></span></a>
    </h1>
  </div>

  <br class='us'>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src='Scripts/scrollSmooth.js'> </script>
  <!-- <script src='Scripts/i_am_a.js'> </script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the `CSS` code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'mainFont';
  src: url("../Fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Medium.ttf") format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'descFont';
  src: url("../Fonts/Poppins/Poppins-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
}

.project_button {
  font-family: 'descFont';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; 

  background-color: #181818;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  /* padding: 20px; */

  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 4px 6px;
  border-radius: 10px;

  cursor: pointer;

  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;

  box-shadow: 0px 16px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
  transition: 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

.project_button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

.banner {
  width: 350px;
  height: 190px;
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: not sure why you need the button, but you could perform onclick event on an image, I think the button might not necessary

Comment: @jialeko what if i need a button? is it possible?

Comment: what i actually want is some text with the image

Comment: and buttons can have texts in them but how about images?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve can you share a sample screenshot?

Comment: Don't ditch the button and just add the onclick event to an image. That would be really bad practice if you do it like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<button class='project_button'>Modular FPS Template <img src='../Images/Projects/Modular-FPS.png' /></button>
```

Move your image inside the button.

Comment: Don't add a button inside an a-tag, this doesn't make sense from a logical perspective. if it is a link, use an a-tag. Otherwise use a button. But never use both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the onClick event to the img tag:

```html
<img onClick="window.open("https://example.com")" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>HTML Image</h2>
<button><img src="image.jpg" alt="No Image" width="50" height="30"></button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You didn't close your img tag

Comment: No need to close a image tag. If you want to close image before button. Please add a <span></span> or <p></p> tag.  EX:  <button><p><img src="image.jpg" alt="No Image" width="100" height="30"></p>Submit</button>

Comment: I meanth a slash at the end of the existing img tag

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using a form and using an input with the "image" type like this:

```
<input type="image" id="myimage" src="[...]" />
```